# Puxando dados repetidos do banco de dados para o DataGridView

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net, datagridview

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em c# onde eu tenho um form `TelaInicio` onde nela  há um `DataGridView` onde são carregadas todas as informações do banco e para isso eu criei um método chamado `CarregarGrid()` no form `TelaInicio`

```
public void CarregarGrid()
    {
        try{
        //indico o número de colunas
        dgvDados.ColumnCount = 14;
        objConnection = new MySqlConnection(caminho);
        //instância do comando onde passo
        //o sql e a conexão como parâmetro
        objComando =  new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM checagens" , objConnection);
        //abro a conexão
        objConnection.Open();
        //instâncio o leitor
        var leitor = objComando.ExecuteReader();
        //enquanto leitor está lendo

        while (leitor.Read())
        {
            //insiro os dados no dgvDados
            dgvDados.Rows.Add(leitor[0].ToString(),
                leitor[1].ToString(),
                leitor[2].ToString(),
                leitor[3].ToString(),
                leitor[4].ToString(),
                leitor[5].ToString(),
                leitor[6].ToString(),
                leitor[7].ToString(),
                leitor[8].ToString(),
                leitor[9].ToString(),
                leitor[10].ToString(),
                leitor[11].ToString(),
                leitor[12].ToString(),
                leitor[13].ToString());

        }
    }
```

Eu chamo esse método no `Form_Load` da `TelaInicio`

```
 private void TelaInicio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarregarGrid();
        dgvDados.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        dgvDados.Columns[0].Name = "CNPJ";
        dgvDados.Columns[1].Name = "DATA";
        dgvDados.Columns[2].Name = "RAZÃO SOCIAL";
        dgvDados.Columns[3].Name = "OPERADORA";
        dgvDados.Columns[4].Name = "LINHAS";
        dgvDados.Columns[5].Name = "VIGENCIA";
        dgvDados.Columns[6].Name = "CONTRATO";
        dgvDados.Columns[7].Name = "VALOR GASTO";
        dgvDados.Columns[8].Name = "FIXO EMPRESA";
        dgvDados.Columns[9].Name = "GESTOR";
        dgvDados.Columns[10].Name = "CELULAR";
        dgvDados.Columns[11].Name = "FIXO GESTOR";
        dgvDados.Columns[12].Name = "EMAIL";
        dgvDados.Columns[13].Name = "OBSERVAÇÕES";
        lblRegistros.Text = (dgvDados.Rows.Count - 1).ToString();    

    }
```

Até ai ok ele puxa todos os dados certinhos para o `DataGridView`, mas eu tenho outro Form chamado `Cadastrar` onde nele faço todo o cadastro das informações e dali já vão direto para o banco, porém se eu deixar o `CarregarGrid()` apenas no `Form_Load` toda vez que eu fizer um novo cadastro para ele atualizar o Grid terei que abrir e fechar o programa, pensando em evitar isso instanciei o método e estou chamando ele após o click do `button` Cadastrar no Form `Cadastrar`

```
 private void btncadastrar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime inicio = dtpvigencia.Value;
        DateTime fim = DateTime.Now;
        int mesesDiff = ajustaMesAno(fim) - ajustaMesAno(inicio);
        if (inicio.Day > fim.Day)
        {
            mesesDiff--;
        }


        Checagem checagem = new Checagem();
        checagem.Cnpj = txtcnpj.Text;
        checagem.Razao = txtrazao.Text;
        checagem.Operadora = cmboperadora.Text;
        checagem.Linhas = txtlinhas.Text;
        checagem.Vigencia = dtpvigencia.Text;
        checagem.MesesContrato = mesesDiff.ToString();
        checagem.ValorGasto = txtvalorgasto.Text;
        checagem.Fixoempresa = txtfixoempresa.Text;
        checagem.Gestor = txtgestor.Text;
        checagem.Celular = txtcelular.Text;
        checagem.Fixogestor = txtfixogestor.Text;
        checagem.Email = txtemail.Text;
        checagem.Obs = txtobs.Text;


        if (cadchecagem(checagem))
        {

            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Dados cadastrados com sucesso ", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            Utilidades.Funcoes.LimparCampos(gbchecagem);
            this.telainicio.CarregarGrid(); //Chamada do método


        }
    }
```

O problema é que após o click do botão ele carrega todas as informações que já estão no `DataGridView` tudo de novo eu gostaria que isso não acontecesse que **ele atualizasse apenas com o cadastro que foi feito naquele momento**, estive pensando em vários jeitos mas não obtive êxito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o seu código a solução seria limpar a lista antes de de carregar, poderia utilizar o `this.dgvDados.Rows.Clear();`

Ficaria assim:

```
public void CarregarGrid()
{
    try{

    // 
    this.dgvDados.Rows.Clear();

    //indico o número de colunas
    dgvDados.ColumnCount = 14;
    objConnection = new MySqlConnection(caminho);
    //instância do comando onde passo
    //o sql e a conexão como parâmetro
    objComando =  new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM checagens" , objConnection);
    //abro a conexão
    objConnection.Open();
    //instâncio o leitor
    var leitor = objComando.ExecuteReader();
    //enquanto leitor está lendo

    while (leitor.Read())
    {
        //insiro os dados no dgvDados
        dgvDados.Rows.Add(leitor[0].ToString(),
            leitor[1].ToString(),
            leitor[2].ToString(),
            leitor[3].ToString(),
            leitor[4].ToString(),
            leitor[5].ToString(),
            leitor[6].ToString(),
            leitor[7].ToString(),
            leitor[8].ToString(),
            leitor[9].ToString(),
            leitor[10].ToString(),
            leitor[11].ToString(),
            leitor[12].ToString(),
            leitor[13].ToString());

    }
}
```

**Outra Solução**

Uma outra forma de apresentar os dados na gridview e de um jeito mais organizado seria utilizando o `dataGridView.DataSource`, ele recebe um obejcto, tu poderias organizar os teus dados em classes exemplo:

- Cria uma classe `Checagens` onde terá todos os teus atributos

  ```
  public class Checagens
  {
    public string Atributo1{ get; set; }
    public string Atributo2{ get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Cria uma outra classe para as operações com a base de dados referente a essa class ou tabela, exemplo: gravar, editar,consultas etc...

  ```
     public class ChecagensBLL
     {
        public void Gravar()
        {

        }

        public void Editar()
        {

        }

        // E outros médotos
       public List<Checagens> Listar()
       {
          List<Checagens>  lista= new List<Checagens>();

         // Aqui coloque o teu código e preencha a lista

        return lista;
       }

  }
  ```
- No teu método carregar grid ficaria desse jetio:

  ```
  public void CarregarGrid()
  {
      ChecagensBLL bll = new ChecagensBLL();
      List<Checagens> lista = bll.Listar();
      dgvDados.DataSource = lista;

  }
  ```

  Para personalizar ou organizar as colunas

  **sintaxe:** dgvDados.Columns[posição da coluna].Propriedades(HeaderText,Visible etc...)

  Para editar o texto da primeira coluna:

  ```
  public void CarregarGrid()
  {
      ChecagensBLL bll = new ChecagensBLL();
      List<Checagens> lista = bll.Listar();
      dgvDados.DataSource = lista;

      if(dgvDados.RowCount>0)
      {
         dgvDados.Columns[0].HeaderText="CNPJ";
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: o `this.dgvDados.Rows.Clear();` já resolveu a situação muito obrigado, mas isso que você mencionou é uma alternativa interessante

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar antes na primeira linha do `public void CarregarGrid()` o código: `dgvDados.Update();
 dgvDados.Refresh();`